# Reason for inversion in "peut-être es-tu une dinde !"

Tags: grammaire, exclamations, inversion

I saw it in the tale *Le Vilain Caneton*. I don't understand how come there's an inversion "es-tu" if it isn't a question?

The whole sentence:

> Tu n'es pas comme les autres, peut-être es-tu une dinde !

Comment: Perhaps this is a rather silly question and inversion also takes place when expressing a doubt or making a conjecture. Which make sense since they all are questions of some sort. But I am light years far from being fluent in French so I need to hear what you guys say.

Comment: @Legomononc'bléd'Ingres so it isn't correct then?

Comment: Just saying there's a spelling mistake with [_peut-être_](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/peut-%C3%AAtre/60050?q=peut-%C3%AAtre#59680) in the source material (a [retelling](http://www.thefrenchexperiment.com/stories/uglyduckling/) of the original [tale](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Le_Vilain_Petit_Canard_%28Andersen-Soldi%29) for learners). Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regardless of whether it is explicitly a question or not, the inversion is the rule in French when a sentence starts with *Peut-être* unless it is *Peut-être que*.

- *Peut-être es-tu une dinde !* is very correct and literary.
- *Peut-être tu es une dinde !* is very incorrect but might be heard in lazy/broken/childish French.
- *Peut-être que tu es une dinde !* is what you commonly hear in spoken French.

References: [oqlf](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3472) and [cntl](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/peut-%C3%AAtre).

Comment: That was very useful to know, thank you very much

Comment: @jiliagre : il y a une petite faute de conjugaison sur la version avec inversion du sujet (deuxième personne du singulier).

Comment: @Legomononc'bléd'Ingres Claudel a sûrement voulu éviter « Peut-être *sera-ce* le matin » qui, bien que correct, heurte l'oreille.

Comment: Re: « _Peut-être ce sera le matin._ » (Claudel) : possible. // Voir aussi au _LBU_ §383 et ss. pour certaines nuances (_peut-être_ ailleurs qu'en début de phrase, ou séparé de l'inversion par d'autres éléments etc.) et des exemples toujours surprenants, tel « _Peut-être il redoute mon contact._ » (Jouhandeau), possiblement senti comme « négligé » en effet.// +1

Comment: Literary* (pas litterary)

Answer (score 1):

This is not strange. You must pronounce it like an exclamation not a question.
it sounds better to me than "peut-être tu es une dinde !" (which is what most people would probably say nowadays).

Comment: Indeed this is quite common for interpolated clauses (called *propositions incises* in French), but less common in speech than in writting.

Comment: Most people would say *Peut-être **que** tu es une dinde !*