# Where to place "peut-être" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire, ordre-des-mots, adverbes, constructions

> 1. Une telle vie m'attirera **peut-être** irrésistiblement un jour.
> 2. Une telle vie m'attirera irrésistiblement **peut-être** un jour.
> 3. Une telle vie m'attirera irrésistiblement un jour, **peut-être**.
> 4. **Peut-être** une telle vie m'attirera irrésistiblement un jour.
> 5. **Peut-être qu**'une telle vie m'attirera irrésistiblement un jour.

Do all of these five sentences essentially work the same way? Or is any of them preferable to the others?

Also, I’m curious to see if there is any notable difference between the fourth and fifth version (whether to include "que" or not).

Comment: The 4th seems wrong to me. The 5th is the correct version. First, second and third seem correct to me. It may only be a matter of style IMO.

Comment: "Une telle vie, peut-être, m'attirera irrésistiblement un jour" is also a possibility.

Comment: Only the second sounds odd to me. @Kii : 4th is not wrong, the "qu'" is often dropped after "Peut-être", especially in literature.

Comment: @Stéphane Si *peut-être* est placé en **début de phrase** sans être suivie d'une complétive **l'inversion du sujet est obligatoire**, sans pour autant faire de la phrase une question. Voir [cette réponse sur French Language](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/17066/358) et  sur la [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3472). If you drop the *que* without inverting the subject it is not literary **it a mistake**.

Comment: @Laure Agreed : *Peut-être une telle vie m'attirera-t-elle irrésistiblement un jour.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They all seem possible with *peut-être* (maybe) getting different scopes:

1. maybe => *irrésistiblement*
2. maybe => *un jour*
3. maybe => *une telle vie m'attirera irrésistiblement un jour*
4. maybe => *une telle vie m'attirera irrésistiblement un jour*
5. maybe => *une telle vie m'attirera irrésistiblement un jour*

In (3), the modality is presented as an afterthought while (4) and (5) express a possibility. There is a stylistic difference between the standard (5) and the litterary (4).

Comment: # 4 is not correct. See my comment above to @Stéphane.

Comment: @Laure Well, Google has many occurrences of this construction with subject inversion in literary context, for example: *Peut-être une telle philosophie ne devait-elle pas être un système.* The argument made on the sites cited are about a sentence with a clitic subject *tu* and I agree these are not grammatical without the subject inversion but it is possible when the subject is a full NP: *Peut-être une telle infinité n'existe pas de fait.* Nothing in your source material seems to suggest otherwise.

Comment: Your example *Peut-être une telle philosophie ne devait-elle pas être un système* **has** the subject inversion. [*Si le sujet est un nom, l’inversion se manifeste par l’ajout d’un pronom sujet placé après le verbe. Cette inversion, habituelle à l’écrit, n’est pas toujours présente à l’oral.*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3472) Some people will not make the inversion orally (and not in literature) so as @jlliagre said it "is very incorrect but might be heard in lazy/broken/childish French".

Comment: My point is that if people come to FL to learn French and are likely to take exams the least we should to  is to point at what will be considered wrong the day they will take an exam.

Comment: @Laure you're right, but 4) definitively is used. Sorry I cannot give an exemple.

Comment: In other words I'd say the `qu'` (of which the only grammatical function is to introduce the subordonate here)  may be dropped (and it is) because it is particulary obvious…

Peut-être me comprendrez-vous… (well yes, it is mainly used with inversion…) but not any time… if I find an exemple I'll come back post it here ! ;)

Comment: @Stéphane If you need examples I can give you plenty... kids say it all the time, and some adults as well, but it is not considered as correct and as I said in my previous comment "if people come to FL to learn French and are likely to take exams the least we should to is to point at what will be considered wrong the day they will take an exam."

Comment: @Laure OK, I'll keep that in mind.